# Spring Batch: unit test late binding

Tags: testing, spring-batch, late-binding

I have reader configured as below:

```
<bean name="reader" class="...Reader" scope="step">
    <property name="from" value="#{jobParameters[from]}" />
    <property name="to" value="#{jobParameters[to]}" />
    <property name="pageSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="saveState" value="false" /> <!-- we use a database flag to indicate processed records -->
</bean>
```

and a test for it like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:testApplicationContext.xml"})
@ActiveProfiles({"default","mock"})
@TestExecutionListeners( {StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
public class TestLeadsReader extends    AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Autowired
private ItemStreamReader<Object[]> reader;

public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
    StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
    execution.getExecutionContext().putLong("campaignId", 1);
    execution.getExecutionContext().putLong("partnerId", 1);

    Calendar.getInstance().set(2015, 01, 20, 17, 12, 00);
    execution.getExecutionContext().put("from", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    Calendar.getInstance().set(2015, 01, 21, 17, 12, 00);
    execution.getExecutionContext().put("to", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return execution;
}

@Test
public void testMapper() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        assertNotNull(reader.read());
    }
    assertNull(reader.read());
}
```

Now, although the pageSize and saveState are injected correctly into my reader, the job parameters are not. According to the documentation this is all that it needs to be done and the only issues I found were about using jobParameters['from'] instead of jobParameters[from]. Any idea what could be wrong?

Also, the open(executionContext) method is not called on my reader before it enters the test method, which is not ok, because I use those job parameters to retrieve some data that needs to be available when the read method is called. This might be related to the above problem though, because the documentation concerning testing with late binding says that "The reader is initialized and bound to the input data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `from` and `to` as step execution context variables in your test. But in your application context configuration you are retrieving them as job parameters. You should set them as job parameters in your unit test.

Also, if you want the open/update/close `ItemStream` lifecycle methods to be called, you should execute the step. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtils.html#launchStep-java.lang.String-org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters-

Comment: The StepExecution does not provide a way to set JobParameters, but only to retrieve them. I have tried using instead the JoScopeTestExecutionListener just the way it is described in itsndocumentation, but I received an exception when creating the execution context complaining about TestInstance being a class when an interface was expected (if I remember correctly)

Comment: And the JobExecution doesn't allow setting the JobParameters either, so which would be the proper way to do that?

Comment: The above answer is correct, it's just I did not pay attention to the MetaDataInstanceFactory which indeed provides a method for creating a step execution using jobParameters: MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution(jobParameters). This link was also helpful: http://code.google.com/p/springbatch-in-action/source/browse/trunk/sbia/ch14/src/test/java/com/manning/sbia/ch14/batch/integration/reader/ReaderWithListenerTest.java?r=245 .